# Is there a way to see not provided keywords in Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics, not-provided

We have set up GA on several websites to gather information about traffic to the site. We know about the organic keywords that are displayed under the Acquisition section of the traffic report. But we have been asked to find a way to display "not provided" keywords typed in by the end user in our Google Analytics report.

Is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You see "not provided" in Google Analytics because when the user came to your site from Google, the "referrer URL" did not contain the search keyword.   It used to be that search engines would always provide the search keyword in the referrer URL.

Since Google is not sending this data, there is no direct way to recover it.    The only data that Google provides about the queries that show your site comes from [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).  In Webmaster Tools, you can see all the queries that show your site in the SERPs.   You can also [link this data to your Google Analytics account](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1120006?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! you can accomplish your "Not provided" keywords if you follow some tactics. here is the link http://moz.com/blog/easing-the-pain-of-google-keyword-not-provided

Comment: Technically, none of the options there (apart from GWT) actually get you the specific keywords users typed into Google to get to your site. But it's a good resource nonetheless.